# Airflow Task Succeeded But Not All Data Ingested

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I have an airflow task to extract data with this flow

```
PostgreSQL -> Google Cloud Storage -> BigQuery
```

The problem that I have is, it seems not all the data is ingested into BigQuery. on the PostgreSQL source, the table has 18M+ rows of data, but after ingested it only has 4M+ rows of data.

When I check on production, the data return 18M+ rows with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM my_table

-- This return 18M+ rows
```

But after the DAG finished running, when I check on BigQuery:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM data_lake.my_table

-- This return 4M+ rows
```

To take notes, not all the tables that I ingested returned like this. All of the smaller tables ingested just fine. But when it hits a certain amount of rows it behaves like this.

My suspicion is when the data is extracted from PostgreSQL to Google Cloud Storage. So I'll provide my function here:

```
    def create_operator_write_append_init(self, worker=10):
        worker_var  = dict()
        with TaskGroup(group_id=self.task_id_init) as tg1:
            for i in range(worker):
                worker_var[f'worker_{i}'] = PostgresToGCSOperator(
                    task_id = f'worker_{i}',
                    postgres_conn_id = self.conn_id,
                    sql = 'extract_init.sql',
                    bucket = self.bucket,
                    filename = f'{self.filename_init}_{i}.{self.export_format}',
                    export_format = self.export_format, # the export format is json
                    gzip = True,
                    params = {
                        'worker': i
                    }
                )
        return tg1
```

and here is the SQL file:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       created_at,
       updated_at,
       deleted_at
FROM my_table
WHERE 1=1
AND ABS(MOD(hashtext(id::TEXT), 10)) = {{params.worker}};
```

What I did is I chunk the data and split it into several workers, hence the TaskGroup.

To provide more information. I use Composer:

- composer-2.0.32-airflow-2.3.4
- Large instance
- Worker 8CPU
- Worker 32GB Memory
- Worker 2GB storage
- Worker between 1-16

What are the possibilities of these happening?

Answer (score 4):

`PostgresToGCSOperator` inherits from `BaseSQLToGCSOperator`(https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/sql_to_gcs/index.html)

According to source code, `approx_max_file_size_bytes=1900000000`. So if you split your table into 10 parts (or workers lets say) the maximum size of this chunk should  be maximum 1.9 gigabyte. In case this chunk is bigger, the previous chunk will be replaced with the new one as you did not specify to create "chunks of your chunk" by PostgresToGCSOperator.

You can to it by adding placeholder {} in the `filename` and the Operator will handle it.

```
def create_operator_write_append_init(self, worker=10):
        worker_var  = dict()
        with TaskGroup(group_id=self.task_id_init) as tg1:
            for i in range(worker):
                worker_var[f'worker_{i}'] = PostgresToGCSOperator(
                    task_id = f'worker_{i}',
                    postgres_conn_id = self.conn_id,
                    sql = 'extract_init.sql',
                    bucket = self.bucket,
                    filename = f'{self.filename_init}_{i}_part_{{}}.{self.export_format}',                    
                    export_format = self.export_format, # the export format is json
                    gzip = True,
                    params = {
                        'worker': i
                    }
                )
        return tg1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try the placeholder and get back to you. because I needed this fast last week what I did is vertically scale the composer instance. it worked but I know it's not the best practice. If there are other needs that require me to ingest large tables again I'll try this method and come back here if it works.

Comment: Could I kindly ask you to upvote my answer if that helped you to understand a concept?

Comment: Yes, I already upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet for it can be visible on the post :)

Comment: This is very useful! I couldn't find this information in the documentation. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely can explore Apache 2.0 licensed [Astro SDK](https://astro-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/) maintained by Astronomer which allows rapid and clean development of {Extract, Load, Transform} workflows using Python and SQL, powered by Apache Airflow.

In this case, `aql.transform_file` can be used to run the SQL query from the `.sql` file and select the data from Postgres. `aql.export_to_file()` would export the data from the Postgres table to the GCS bucket. And finally `aql.load_file()` can be used to load data from a file from GCS to BigQuery. Following is the example DAG:

```
from airflow.models.dag import DAG

from astro.files import File
from astro.constants import FileType
from astro.table import Table
from astro.sql.operators.load_file import load_file
from astro.sql.operators.export_to_file import export_to_file
from astro.sql.operators.transform import transform_file
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

POSTGRES_CONN_ID ="postgres_conn"

with DAG(
        dag_id="sample-dag",
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        catchup=False,
) as dag:
    postgres_table = Table(name="my_table", temp=True, conn_id=POSTGRES_CONN_ID)

    postgres_data = transform_file(
        file_path=f"{Path(__file__).parent.as_posix()}/transform.sql",
        parameters={"input_table": postgres_table},
    )


    save_file_to_gcs = export_to_file(
        task_id="save_file_to_gcs",
        input_data=postgres_data,
        output_file=File(
            path="gs://astro-sdk/all_postgres_data.csv",
            conn_id="gcp_conn",
        ),
        if_exists="replace",
    )

    load_data_to_bq = load_file(
        input_file=File(
            "gs://astro-sdk/all_postgres_data.csv",
            conn_id="gcp_conn",
            filetype=FileType.CSV,
        ),
        output_table=Table(conn_id="gcp_conn"),
        use_native_support=False,
        native_support_kwargs={
            "ignore_unknown_values": True,
            "allow_jagged_rows": True,
            "skip_leading_rows": "1",
        },
        enable_native_fallback=True,
    )
    load_data_to_bq.set_upstream(save_file_to_gcs)
```

Adding the screenshot the for DAG run.
[DAG screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MRz1.png)

Hence using astro-sdk-python instead would just simplify the approach.

We have various operators and decorators as part of this project which is described here: https://astro-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/

Disclaimer: I work at [Astronomer](https://www.astronomer.io/), which develops Astro SDK as an Open Source project.